# Drupal 7 "Panels"

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-panels

I want to know about Drupal 7 module "Panels", and to know how to work on it, how it is useful in creating panes and customising it.

like the right top side in the below website. http://www.newsclick.in.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to look at this screencast:

http://dev.nodeone.se/node/770

Not just Panels but also how it works with page manager and views.

Comment: Then you might wanna mark my answer as a working solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Kristoffer is correct.  Looking at the right side of the website you linked, a lot of the functionality is found in views. You might use panels to handle appearance and views to address content. They work together very well. If your new to Drupal, I suggest you focus on the functionality and deal with the appearance after.  Nodeone also has an excellent video series on Views called "Taming the Beast" which you will want to study before attempting to link views and panels.

Answer (score 0):

Panels are mostly used to create customized layouts for multiple uses. You can create a page having different regions. It has a drag and drop content manager. Please read [Panels module](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels)